# Less loop to increment padding in UL > LI > A

Tags: html, css, less

I have the following hierarchy in my html.

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <a></a>
   <ul>
   <li>
   <a></a>
     <ul>
      <li>
      <a></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I want to increment the padding only in anchor element. I have come up with the following loop in less but it's only increment the padding in ul li. I can't figure out how to select the anchor element.

```
.make-nested-lists(5);

.make-nested-lists(@n, @i: 0) when (@i < @n) {
    ul li {
        padding-left: (30px + 15 * @i);
        .make-nested-lists(@n, (@i + 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the `padding` on your `a` instead of your `li` :

```
.make-nested-lists(5);

.make-nested-lists(@n, @i: 0) when (@i < @n) {
    ul li {
        a{
            padding-left: (30px + 15 * @i);
        }

        .make-nested-lists(@n, (@i + 1));
    }
}
```

***Demo (with the compiled LESS):***

```css
ul li a{padding-left:30px}ul li ul li a{padding-left:45px}ul li ul li ul li a{padding-left:60px}ul li ul li ul li ul li a{padding-left:75px}ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li a{padding-left:90px}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>test 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>test 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a>test 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @GaniduRanasinghe Yes it does, try it.

Answer (score 0):

add p adding to your link (a), not on li element.